# Source code highlighter for HTML5 that uses CSS classes

Tags: html, css, highlighting

I am going to rewrite a project that currently uses Pygments in Crystal. I need a replacement for Pygments. It doesn't have to be a library, it can be a standalone binary I call out to.

I found GNU source-highlight, which I thought for a while would do but it seems to only support `color` attributes  and not `class` attributes, which prevents me from using a runtime stylesheet (I have a dark mode switch that changes the background color of code blocks, which must also change the code colors to keep them readable).

I'm not okay with using a Javascript-based solution. This must work with Javascript disabled.

Ideally the set of CSS classes it outputs is simpler than Pygments; I'd rather have a simpler stylesheet than be able to color a bunch of different categories of keywords differently. I do need to be able to define classes that go for all languages with generic categories like "keyword", "type", "literal", rather than a different scheme for each language (it's not that I *want* them to be the same, just that I don't want my code to be concerned with every language the highlighter supports). I do not need the ability to add my own languages, only that all common languages (ie. top 20 or so) are supported.